# Check on understanding Primary Decomposition Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials, primary-decomposition

I've learned the Primary decomposition theorem recently and wanted to check if I have this right. Is this example correctly applied?

Let $V$ be finite dim. and $T$ a linear map on $V$.

Suppose $m_T(x)=x(x-1)^5(x^2+1)^2$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Then by the PDT, $V=\ker T \bigoplus \ker (T-I)^5 \bigoplus \ker (T^2+I)^2$

and $m_{T|_{\ker (T-I)}}=(x-1)^5$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.